# SPSS syntax IF statement -> Multiple recode commands

Tags: if-statement, spss

I am trying to recode multiple variables with one IF statement. SPSS however does not like me doing so (I am probably missing something in the syntax, but I do not know what).

Example syntax:

```
IF (Var1=X) Var2=1 Var3=2 Var4=1.
Execute.
```

So I want SPSS to change variable 1, 2 and three if Var1=X. If I write the syntax like the example I get the error: The expression ends unexpectedly (at the start of the Var3=2 recode).

So my question is: how should I write the syntax to get SPSS to recode multiple variables with one IF statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up [`DO IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_if.htm?lang=en) statement and the distinction between that and a [`IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_if.htm?lang=en) statement, to better understand how each operates and help aid answer your question.

```
* Assuming Var1 is a string else just enter a numeric without quotes .
DO IF (Var1="X").
    COMPUTE Var2=1
    COMPUTE Var3=2
    COMPUTE Var4=1.
END IF.
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed!